# How can I use a CSV file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

When I did it using an online tutorial, it kept telling me that there was an error with quotations, but after editing, I still don't see the problem. CAn you please help?

```
import csv
with open("CSV_birthdays.txt") as csv_file:
    csv_converter = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',') # This suggests that commas seperate classes
    linenum = 0
    for row in csv_converter:
        if linenum == 0:
            print("There are 4 family members I have dealt with so far")
            linenum +=1 # go to the next line
        else: # for the actual columns printing out my sentences
            print(f"\t{row[0]} is {row[1]} years old, and they were born on the {row[2]}th) of {row[3]}{row[4]}.")
            linenum += 1 # print the next line
    print(f"I have the birthdays of {linenum} people")
```

This is the csv file I'm referring to

```
name, age, birthday ,birthday month, birth year
me, 15, 17, March, 2005
my sister, 13 , 1 , 8, 3006
Manson, 10, 22, 11, 2009
Fred, 15, 7, 6, 2004
```

Comment: Can you also share the exception?

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by that?

Comment: sorry. i saw this on the internet and thought that this may be neccessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the the file name to "CSV_birthdays.csv"

Then use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("CSV_birthdays.csv")
df.head()
df.tail()
df.info()
df.describe()
```

Comment: What is pandas?

Comment: Pandas is the go to library for working with data in python. first you need to install it.
https://pandas.pydata.org/
you can use pip to install it or conda

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I may not have understood what pandas is, but you have helped me to understand my errors.

```
import csv
with open("birthday.txt") as csv_file:
    csv_converter = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',') # This suggests that commas seperate classes
    linenum = 0
    for row in csv_converter:
        if linenum == 0:
            print("There are 4 family members I have dealt with so far")
            linenum +=1 # go to the next line
        else: # for the actual columns printing out my sentences
            name = ''.join(row[0])
            age = ''.join(row[1])
            birthday =''.join(row[2])
            birthmonth =''.join(row[3])
            birthyear = ''.join(row[4])

            print (name +" is" + age +" years old, and they were born on the " + birthday + "of " + birthmonth + "" + birthyear +".")
            linenum += 1 # print the next line
        print("\there is the original format")
        print ','.join(row)
```